# Test Kafka listener with custom container factory in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, testcontainers, spring-kafka-test, spring-boot-testcontainers

I'm having big troubles trying to test a kafka listener.

The class is the following:

```kotlin
@Component
class KafkaListener(
       private val useCase: UseCase
) {
   @KafkaListener(
           topics = ["topic"],
           groupId = "demo",
           // this is giving me problems, everything works well when I remove it
           containerFactory = "containerFactory",
           clientIdPrefix = "prefix"
   )
   fun listener(message: String) {
       println("message received!")
       useCase.foo()
   }
}
```

The test:

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration
class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    fun containerFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory1<String, String> {
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory1<String, String>()
        val props = HashMap<String, Any?>()
        props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "127.0.0.1:9092"
        val defaultConsumer = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props, StringDeserializer(), StringDeserializer())
        factory.consumerFactory = defaultConsumer

        return factory
    }
}

@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest"])
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [MongoAutoConfiguration::class])
@Import(KafkaListener::class, TestConfig::class)
class KafkaShippingGroupCreationListenerAdapterTest {

    companion object {
        @Container
        private val kafkaContainer = KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.3"))

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun overrideProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
        }
    }

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var useCase: UseCase

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, Any>

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var kafkaListener: KafkaListener

    @Test
    fun `should invoke the use case`() {
        kafkaTemplate.send("topic", "message")

        verify(useCase,
                timeout(5000).times(1)).foo()
    }
}
```

Everything works well when I don't specify a factory in the listener function but when I specify a factory the listener is not being updated with the kafka boostrap server given by the container.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect it to work? Boot's auto configured factory uses the `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` property set up in the test, but yours is hard coded to `"127.0.0.1:9092"`.

Comment: Please note the line where the spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers is being overriden. That works perfect when I don't use a factory.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean; it is clearly hard coded in your custom factory `>props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "127.0.0.1:9092"`

Comment: yes it's hardcoded because I have to set a value there but when the container is up and running the boostrap server changes and therefore the property spring.kafka.boostrap-servers is updated but the listener is still listening in the same port. 

registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);

Comment: So, add `@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-server}") String bootstrap;` to your TestConfig (instead of hard coding it) and use `bootstrap` in your factory config. You can either add it as a field or as a parameter to the factory method for the factory bean definition. I guess it's `fun containerFactory(@Value("...") bootstrap : String)` in Kotlin.

Comment: it worked by adding the @Value to the factory arguments, thanks you Gary